# OpenVPN setup for two (2) workplace networks

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I have 2 office locations with same ISP, different IP, each having up to 10 computers in their networks.

I want to setup a VPN Server in the first location, using Ubuntu and OpenVPN / PPTP, and connect all the computers from the two locations to the same server.

I want all the computers to see each other shared folders, shared printers and so on.

Is VPN the solution here ? If it's not I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you in advance, and if I wasn't clear enough please post a reply and I will try to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, having a site-to-site split-tunnel VPN is a good solution for this. Generally, you'd run this service on the edge firewall at each site if possible. If you must run this on a dedicated machine, it effectively becomes a router/firewall as well adding complexity to your network and an additional point of failure. It's perfectly do-able, but it might be a better idea to look at the site-to-site functionality of your existing firewalls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand this correct, I will use the dedicated machine as a VPN Server as well as a Router/Firewall system.

Comment: I already have a router in each location, the server must be outside the lan network provided by the router, in the first location ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding what you're trying to say.